# Does the Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) wiki support syntax highlighting?

Tags: azure-devops, wiki

Visual Studio Team Services has a Markdown-based project documentation feature in form of a wiki.

However I do not get the code formatting to work.

It looks like this:

[image]

but obviously it should look like this:

[image]

Is syntax highlighting not supported in Visual Studio Team Services or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have a used the language identifier in Markdown Syntax as csharp does not seem to be recognized by default.

Check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance) for Syntax guidance for Markdown files, widgets, wikis, and pull request comments.

Also, you may go through this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/07/06/33855/).